# Web scraping from google search results but can't get results

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-search

I'm trying to use Selenium to scrape the list of sponsored items separately for around 1000 keywords.  I can successfully get the sponsored URL for the first several keywords, however, it's failed for the rest of the keywords even though it does have sponsored ads.

Here's the code

```
def get_ads_url(keywords):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, options= chrome_options)

    google_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={}'.format(keywords) 


    driver.get(google_url)
    pause = float( random.randint(1, 2) + random.randint(1, 5)/ 10)
    time.sleep(pause)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
    sponsored_items = soup.select("div[data-text-ad='1'] span[role='text']")

    sponsored_list = []
    for item in sponsored_items:
        text = item.get_text(strip = True).split()
        if len(text) > 0:
            sponsored_list.append(text[0])

    final_result = list(set(sponsored_list))

    print(final_result)
    driver.quit()

    return final_result



Example


keyword: nike
google_url:https://www.google.com/search?q=nike
Expected Result : ['https://www.nike.com.tw', 
                   'https://www.adidas.com.tw',
                   'https://www.farfetch.com']
```

I'm not really sure whether I got block from Google search or not. Feel free to share me your thoughts. Thanks

[Sponsored items for Nike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNlDn.png)

Comment: could you add part of the results and the difference between sponsored and not sponsored results?

Comment: @Gugu72 Hello, I've updated the sample and the screenshot for how to define sponsored items.

Comment: @JammyWang there might not always be sponsor ads when you load the page. You could test for keywords. For that add `input()` to halt the program if no sponsor link is found then inspect the browser opened by selenium to find the problem.

Comment: @DanielSabrel Yh, ikr. If there's no sponsored ads then, it'll return an empty list. but somehow I couldn't get the sponsored ads URL when it does exist. Not sure whether I got blocked or other reasons.

Comment: @JammyWang If you can see the sponsored ads in driver instance, you **will** be able to retrieve the url. Just add `input()` to your code to pause the code execution then inspect the browser opened by selenium and check if your selector in `soup.select` is correct.

Comment: @DanielSabrel Thanks for your advice. I'm gotta check it then.  Feel free to let me know if you have others thoughts

Comment: try using [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) while at it, `WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'appbar')))`. For my location, ID is appbar for search-result container. It might be different for yours

Comment: wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)    

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-text-ad='1']")))  

elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-text-ad='1']//span[@role='text']") 


Yh, I was using the WebDriverWait in the beginning (as above), however, it took lots of time to run it completely. So, I switched to another way without using it to save time.  I'll make a try as well.

I thought it should be the recaptcha issues from Google that made Selenium can't fetch the webpage smoothly since Im repeatedly sending the requests.

Comment: It's just speculation: the reason it was taking a lot of time might be because you were searching for element that didn't always exist. If it didn't exist, it would throw Timeouterror which people always catch and pass. So you can wait till something that will always load like the one that says `About x results (y seconds)` then search for other elements using find_element or bs4

Comment: You can include time delay along with selenium wait.

Comment: much appreciated. I'll check it step by step. Thanks, again